# CorePlot - multiLine attributed label

Tags: ios, core-plot

I am trying to create a custom label for `coreplot` using `NSAttributedString`. Everything works fine when my strings have 1 line.

The problem occurs when I want to have 2 line strings using code:

```
NSMutableAttributedString* remFinalLabel = [remAttrStr mutableCopy];
NSMutableAttributedString *newLineAttrStr = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc]initWithString:@"\n"];
[remFinalLabel appendAttributedString:newLineAttrStr];
[remFinalLabel appendAttributedString:rem2AttrStr];
```

The result looks like that: not even first string is properly displayed. How can I set the number of lines in custom label?

[image]

My code to create labels:

```
NSMutableArray* labelsStrings = [NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects:strAttr1, strAttr2, strAttr3, nil];
NSMutableArray *ticksLocations = [NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects:@0.5, @1.5, @2.5, nil];
NSMutableArray* customLabels = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
NSUInteger labelLocation = 0;

@try {
    for (NSNumber *tickLocation in ticksLocations) {
        NSAttributedString* currentLabel = [labelsStrings objectAtIndex:labelLocation];

        CPTTextLayer *txtLayer = [[CPTTextLayer alloc] initWithAttributedText:currentLabel];
        CPTAxisLabel* newLabel = [[CPTAxisLabel alloc] initWithContentLayer:txtLayer];

        newLabel.tickLocation = tickLocation;
        newLabel.offset = 0.0f;
        newLabel.alignment = CPTAlignmentLeft;
        [customLabels addObject:newLabel];
        labelLocation++;
    }
}
@catch (NSException * e) {
    DLog(@"An exception occurred while creating date labels for x-axis");
}
@finally {
    y.axisLabels =  [NSSet setWithArray:customLabels];
}
y.majorTickLocations = [NSSet setWithArray:ticksLocations];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve this by setting the frame of content layer of your **CPTAxisLabel**.

Try this:-

```
    CPTAxisLabel *label = [[CPTAxisLabel alloc] initWithText:@"Your Text Here" textStyle:@"Text Style"];
    [label.contentLayer setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 40, 40)]; //change this frame according to your requirement
```

Happy Coding..!!

Comment: The text layer sizes itself to fit the text automatically. This step should be unnecessary.

Comment: Worked for me. Thanks!